# Accidentally edited someones else's answer

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I was editing my answer and didn't notice that I accidentally edited someone else's answer. I mean I actually re-wrote it and after posting to SO, I'm trying to re-edit that answer and cannot restore the actual answer. Is there any way to restore it?

Comment: You should see a "edited by ... XY ago" at the bottom of the answer. Click on it and you can see all revisions where you can roll back to a particular one. You even get a badge for this!

Comment: @Rizier123 let me try

Comment: Do you mean [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12798408)? That has been rejected by OP. So nothing to worry about.

Comment: SO is great and I think I need to be careful next time

Comment: Happened to me once. Made the other answer better than mine :) so deleted my own answer and upvoted the one I accidentally edited.

Comment: @Rizier123 I don't believe users <2k can roll-back edits, because roll-backs are applied immediately and they don't have that power (although they can do it on their own content)

Comment: Also, should you *really* be re-writing answers for others? I've always had the impression that this was discouraged and is rejected usually as *`Conflicts with author's intent`*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you don't have full edit privileges (less than 2K points), your edit must be reviewed. You can wait for the edit to be rejected, as happened in your case.
If your edit accidentally gets approved, you can raise the issue on Meta, like you did - *and* give us a link to the edit. Then someone above 2K can roll it back.
You can also suggest an edit that restores the original post. If you do this, *write in the Edit Summary that it is meant to be a rollback!* Otherwise it will probably be rejected.

If you have full edit privileges, simply click on "edited ... ago", which takes you to the edit history. Then you can click on the appropriate rollback link.

Answer (score 1):

If you edit someone else answer, since you have less than 2k rep, your edit has been added to the edit queue to be validated. No one else will see your edit on the question until it has been approved.

So it won't be visible unless 3 people with the privilege will approve it.

EDIT : The edit was rejected, there is no resulting problem.